# How does RavenDb Sql Replication Work?

Tags: sql-server, ravendb

I've looked through the RavenDB documentation but I can't seem to see how it works, does it poll the database or does it use some sort of notification like sqldependency?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Replication in RavenDB will watch for changes inside RavenDB and apply the script you supplied to send it.
It doesn't use polling

Comment: Thanks for the response :) How is RavenDb aware that there has been a change in SQL? Does it use Query Notification?

Comment: It isn't SQL replication is FROM RavemDB TO SQL